# How to get a bootable disk?

Tags: disk

I've copied ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso to a CD-R disk and put it into my PC. When I set the BIOS to boot from the IDE CD-ROM Device and try to start the machine I get the message: "Strike F1 to retry reboot" and "No boot device available.". Is the file I'm trying to boot from a "bootable" file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to burn the .iso file to the CD-R disk not just copy it over.

Comment: Copy to a CD-R is the same as burn I think. The directory shows the file on that CD-R on the PC but it won't boot from that drive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually burn that ISO to DVD, since it will not fit on a CD, or createa bootable USB.  For the DVD, you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), to get that accomplished, or just take a look at [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Answer (score 1):

To create a bootable disk, find an application called [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) and download it. I assume you're using Windows. After downloading the app, run it whilst you have a flash disk that you want to be bootable attached to your machine. Then it will prompt you to format the disk and make it bootable. Also, you need to specify the **.iso** image file that you want loaded onto the flash disk.

[image: Rufus In Action..]

If you want to create a bootable disk in Ubuntu, find an app called **[Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/)** in your applist, or download it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Now that I have the desktop loaded it runs so slowly that I can't use it. Takes 5 minutes to open Firefox.Do I need to uninstall Windows?

Comment: No need to remove windows. How much hard disk space did you allocate to the ubuntu partition??